# dvd movies not mounting

Tags: 11.10, dvd

ok my problem here is that if I insert a dvd movie into my drive it spins then nothing happens, however if i insert a data dvd it mounts and opens the files within 20 seconds. I have all medibuntu installed and libdvd etc. i am running Ubuntu 11.10 not sure how to proceed as i am new to Ubuntu.

```
*-cdrom
     description: DVD-RAM writer
      product: BDDVDRW CT10N
       vendor: HL-DT-ST
       physical id: 1
       bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0
       logical name: /dev/cdrom1
       logical name: /dev/cdrw1
       logical name: /dev/dvd1
       logical name: /dev/dvdrw1
       logical name: /dev/scd0
       logical name: /dev/sr0
       version: WA02
       capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
       configuration: ansiversion=5 status=nodisc
```

This is what shows with a dvd movie in the drive

```
 *-cdrom
       description: DVD-RAM writer
       product: BDDVDRW CT10N
       vendor: HL-DT-ST
       physical id: 1
       bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0
       logical name: /dev/cdrom1
       logical name: /dev/cdrw1
       logical name: /dev/dvd1
       logical name: /dev/dvdrw1
       logical name: /dev/scd0
       logical name: /dev/sr0
       logical name: /media/GRMCULFRER_BR_DVD
       version: WA02
       capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
       configuration: ansiversion=5 mount.fstype=udf mount.options=ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=77,dmode=500,iocharset=utf8 state=mounted status=ready
     *-medium
          physical id: 0
          logical name: /dev/cdrom1
          logical name: /media/GRMCULFRER_BR_DVD
          configuration: mount.fstype=udf mount.options=ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=77,dmode=500,iocharset=utf8 state=mounted
```

and this is with a data dvd inserted.

anyone please help. let me know if you need any more info

Comment: Is this a problem with auto-started playing or isn't it mounted at all (i.e., does it show up in Nautilus)?

Comment: does not show up in Nautilus or any where for that matter, i have tried several different dvd's as well

Answer (score 1):

Welcome Jarrod

Open the Terminal, and execute the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

To play DVDs, you also need to install libdvdcss by opening a terminal and entering the following in addition to installing the restricted extras package:

```
 sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh
```

additional documentation https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats

Comment: Thank for the advice but i have already tried this to no avail, after reading several threads and tried the most likely things such as restricted extras and libdvd files

Comment: Are you using VLC or something else to try to view the DVD

Comment: yes i have tried to use VLC to view the dvd but it won't load it either